# Renovate bot missing updates on a lot of dependencies

Tags: renovate

I'm using [Renovate bot](https://www.mend.io/free-developer-tools/renovate/) on my personal [blog project](https://github.com/haraldvinje/tekblogg). There are many dependencies in both `package.json` files (see one of them [here](https://github.com/haraldvinje/tekblogg/blob/master/tekblogg-cms/package.json)). Renovate updates some of the dependencies, like [Next.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next), but is missing many others. When I run `yarn upgrade-interactive` today (Jan 30th 2023) I get the following (see screenshot):

[image: Dependencies]

Why has renovate not picked up on this? It has been quite some time since many of these packages were updated, while other packages with recent releases have been updated, so renovate obviously has done some scanning. I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this, so I though I'd ask here.

This is my `renovate.json`:

```
{
  "extends": ["config:base"],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["minor", "patch", "pin", "digest"],
      "automerge": true
    },
    {
      "matchDepTypes": ["devDependencies"],
      "automerge": true
    }
  ],
  "platformAutomerge": true
}
```

Also see [renovate dashboard](https://github.com/haraldvinje/tekblogg/issues).

Hope everything is clear. Thanks in advance.

I have looked at the FAQ and searched Stack overflow.

Comment: Have you looked at Renovate logs? They should give a lot of details and explanation of what was detected or not in your repo and why an update was found or not...

Comment: I also have the same problem. The list of packages that are found feels completely random. Did you ever find a solution?